# Sending a vector of stuct objects through the 'next_permutation' algorithm fails to build

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct

I am having trouble with getting a brute-force algorithm to work. As you can see from my code below, I am trying to evaluate a vector of structs and find the most efficient way to order a series of timed events. Here is my simple struct layout whose objects I am placing in the 'part1Vec' vector:

```
struct person
{
    float swim;
    float bike;
    float run;

    float bikeRun;

    person();

    person(float swim, float bike, float run)
    {
        this->swim = swim;
        this->bike = bike;
        this->run = run;

        this->bikeRun = bike + run;
    };
};
```

However, when I compile I get an error within the algorithm class that I have supposedly traced to this line:

```
while (next_permutation(part1Vec.begin(), part1Vec.end()))
```

the error message I get is this:

```
//Invalid operands to binary expression ('const person' and 'const person')
```

I believe I have the next_permutation function implemented correctly, but I do not understand why it is giving me this error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    float swim;
    float bike;
    float run;

    float bikeRun;

    person();

    person(float swim, float bike, float run)
    {
        this->swim = swim;
        this->bike = bike;
        this->run = run;

        this->bikeRun = bike + run;
    };
};

//function declarations and global variables
vector<person> part1Vec;
vector<person> highestVec;

float highestRating;
float tempRating;

float rating(vector<person> vector);

int main()
{
    //PART 1

    //make objects
    person one(20, 25, 20), two(35, 20, 15), three(40, 20, 30);

    //insert into vector
    part1Vec.push_back(one);
    part1Vec.push_back(two);
    part1Vec.push_back(three);

    cout << "_________swim__bike__run__" << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<part1Vec.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Vector #" << i+1 << ": "
        << part1Vec[i].swim << "  "
        << part1Vec[i].bike << "  "
        << part1Vec[i].run;
    }

    cout << endl << "Calculating..." << endl;

    //Next permutation function
    while (next_permutation(part1Vec.begin(), part1Vec.end())) //Invalid operands to binary expression ('const person' and 'const person')
    {
        //initialize highestVec
        if (highestVec.size() == 0)
        {
            highestRating = rating(part1Vec);
            highestVec = part1Vec;
        }
        //if Highest Rating is less than current permutation, update.
        else if (highestRating < (tempRating = rating(part1Vec)) )
        {
            highestVec = part1Vec;
            highestRating = tempRating;
        }
    }

    cout << "Best Solution:" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<part1Vec.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Vector #" << i+1 << ": "
        << highestVec[i].swim << "  "
        << highestVec[i].bike << "  "
        << highestVec[i].run;
    }

    cout << endl << "Rating: " << highestRating << endl;

    return 0;
}

float rating(vector<person> thisVector)
{
    float rating = 0;
    float swimSum = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<thisVector.size()-1; i++)
    {
        swimSum += thisVector[i].swim;

        if (rating < swimSum + thisVector[i].bikeRun)
            rating = swimSum + thisVector[i].bikeRun;
    }

    return rating;
}
```

Comment: It needs to know how to order your objects.

Answer (score 2):

Kyle Y., did you understand what chris meant?

I hope Chris won't mind, but I'll take the liberty of elaborating just in case.

First up, say what compiler you're using. One reason is that they give different error messages. And in this instance, `Invalid operands to binary expression ('const person' and 'const person')` was kinda useful but not as useful as it could be. If I ran this through `gcc`, for example, it'd probably tell me something more like that `std::next_permuation` was looking for an undefined operator.

[std::next_permuation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) uses a well ordering to generate permutations. So it needs arguments of types with an order defined on themselves, and so that the algorithm will always terminate, a *consistent* order (an ordering is inconsistent if a<(b) and b<(a) is possible, which is generally inadvisable regardless).

That's what chris is referring to, and the way you do that in C++ with say struct types like yours for which order is not already defined by a base class, is to override `bool operator<(...` in the struct.

Because you only need the ordering for your permutation generation, any old ordering will do as long as: everything is ordered and the ordering is consistent, as above.

See [here](http://codepad.org/UKaLzFh2) for your code again with that override and a few `unsigned int`s in where they should be, note:

```
    bool operator<(const person& rhs) const {
    return (this->swim + this->bike + this->run) < (rhs.swim + rhs.bike + rhs.run);
}
```

Best.